# More Efficient Way of making multiple objects

Tags: java, export, lwjgl, slick2d

I am trying to make a memory game with Java. The game is basically going to be some squares in a grid that is 4x4 at the moment just for testing purposes. I have created my Square class, and programmed what i want them to do in that class, and then created a square object in another Class that handles the "Normal Mode" of the game. Now since i have a 4x4 grid of squares I need to make 16 different Squares (Or at least that's what i'm thinking at the moment). I also need to draw the Squares in their corresponding place.

My Question: What is the most efficient way of creating 16 of these Square objects while still being able to manipulate them individually? (Sort of like each having their own name; Square, Square1, Square2, etc).

I am also using the Slick2D library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, Square[][] squareGrid = new Square[4][4] is a good way to go about this;
then you can initialize all 16 of them using:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < squareGrid.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < squareGrid[i].length; j++)
            squareGrid[i][j] = new Square();
```

now each square automatically has its own unique (row, col) id. 
for example,

```
squareGrid[1][2].callSomeFunctionInSquareClass();
```

can be used to manipulate the square at 2nd row, 3rd column. 
This way you will avoid scanning through all the squares to get the one at a particular cell on the grid, thus making it much more efficient.

happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have about 2 questions though. Why use a for loop to initialize, and how is it that you define i and j in the loop. Does the first for loop do the rows, and the second the column, or vice versa?

Comment: 1) you can think of the array as a container that only holds references to the actual objects and until you set those references to some object, it would be null. so by doing squareGrid[i][j] = new Square(), you are literally creating a new Square object and setting it to a reference at index [i][j]. if you don't do that, it would be null at [i][j] and throw the infamous NullPointerException when you try to access any of the Square objects methods and what not using for example squareGrid[1][3].callSomeFunc().

Comment: 2) you can think of it as whichever makes more sense to you. for me, for example in notation array[i][j], I think of the first array or "i" as row and the array within that or "j" as column. you can think of them in vice-versa but makes sure it agrees with the rest of the program to avoid any potential confusion.

Comment: Thanks again, and that explanation helped tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Square[][] grid = new Square[4][4]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Square[][] array, e.g. `Square[][] squares = new Square[4][4]`, and then initialise it with all 16 Squares in two nested loops:

```
for (int x = 0; x < squares.length) x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < squares[x].length; y++)
        squares[x][y] = new Square(x, y);
```

Comment: This will create 16 different squares with different names? I'm sorry, iv'e read about these 2D arrays, but never fully understood them.

Comment: Also, where did you get the .length from? Further more why does this show up "i < squares[i].length;" when that for loop is checking for the int y ?

Comment: @MrPork it will create 16 different objects, but those objects won't have any "names" (I guess you mean variables referencing the objects), but are instead all referenced only in an array. You can define as many variables referencing the same square, e.g. `square = squares[0][0]; square2 = square;`, but this will neither create new Squares nor copy anything.

Comment: @MrPork that's a typo :P

Comment: What is the point of using the for loops for initializing the square array though?Couldn't you just do it like this "squares[4][4] = new Square(x, y)? Why does Square[][] change into Square(x, y)? I am so sorry for all my question, i'm really new to programming, and want all the info i can get.

Comment: @MrPork an array is a list of elements, in this case a list of Squares. All those Squares have to be created somewhere, and two loops are used to make this short, extensible and easy to understand (if one knows arrays).

Comment: You really should read up on basic Java before starting on OpenGL. @MrPork your whole issue is not OpenGL related, but rather basic Java question related.