# Editing all 2D array objects at once?

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, slick2d

So i have created a Square class, created a 2D array in my "NormalMode" class like this:

```
Square[][] square = new Square[4][4]
```

and initialized it with the 2 nested for loops. Now that i have this, how can i run a method from my Square class for all the square objects in the array at the same time?

Comment: The methods will never run at the same time, without the use of Threads, the method calls will be placed on the stack and executed one after the other. You can iterate over the 2D array (16 iterations) calling the method you wish to run for each object of type `Square`

Comment: @JonnyHenly Good Enough, but how can i use the method for all the objects in the Arraylist? Am i obligated to doing this one by one?!

Comment: `Square[][]` is not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Christian I'm so sorry! I'm still new to programming, this is a 2D array right?

Comment: Yes, a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another pair of loops, or use a static method if the method is independent of the Square instances (i.e. if the method doesn't modify or access any instance fields).

If you don't want a static method and you only want the method to be executed once you should put the code into the constructor, or call it from there.

Comment: You are on FIRE today Njol, thanks for the help!

Comment: @MrPork you could alternatively read a guide to programming ;)

Comment: Hello outsiders reading this! To do this loop he is talking about just go here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896694/more-efficient-way-of-making-multiple-objects

Answer (score 4):

You have to do it one by one:

```
for (Square[] arr: square)
    for (Square sq : square)
        sq.someMethod();
```

Comment: Unless he uses threads and triggers each thread to execute a method in each index of `Square[][]` at a given time. I don't know if I said that right, and also there would be no point to do that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but based on the OP' comments I think that's not what he wanted. He could try it later, when he learns more about Java.